# Illegal character in query at index in url

Tags: java, android

```
http://search-gf-slvaax6ij6m7ohb7at3ki2kvua.us-east-1.xxxx.yyy.com/2013-01-01/search?q=abc&facet.mod={sort:'count'}&facet.topic={sort:'count'}
```

> this url gives me a error whwn i access through get method in android
>
> error:Illegal character in query at index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try URL encoding the characters in the querystring, like so:

```
http://search-gf-slvaax6ij6m7ohb7at3ki2kvua.us-east-1.xxxx.yyy.com/2013-01-01/search?q=abc&facet.mod=%7bsort%3a%27count%27%7d&facet.topic=%7bsort%3a%27count%27%7d
```

Comment: its work perfectly but how to encode the url. please specify method.

Comment: See fge's answer. The solution you will require will depend on how you are building this URL in code.

Answer (score 1):

You have three solutions:

- the quick one: use the [constructor of the `URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) class;
- the medium one: use Guava's [`UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html#urlPathSegmentEscaper%28%29) (which does the job for query parameters despite its name);
- the "big" one: use a [URI Template (RFC 6570)](https://github.com/fge/uri-template).

All three will produce reliable results for your needs.